# Xcode Storyboard - making the text rtl with font-awesome

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, font-awesome

I want to use in my button text, an icon taken from font-awesome and a text next to it.

I am using Hebrew text. I need the icon to be RIGHT of the text (not like English, where you have the icon first and then the text).

No matter what I did, I did not succeed with getting this done.

I looked for some kind of RTL attribute (could be in XML) just for the text, but I cannot find anything like it.

Again, I am not looking for RTL support for the entire storyboard. I am just looking for RTL text (on a button or on a label).

How to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this through code:

```
   UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

or follow the steps to make the changes in storyboard

Xcode -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Application Language -> Right-to-Left pseudo language.

Check this for more details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: this does not help. I need the text to be changed on the button regardless of the running scheme. I need some way to change the order of the icon taken from font-awesome and the text next to it, so that the icon will appear to the RIGHT side of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let exercises_heb = "תרגילים"
    let fa_cubes = "" // this is a Font Awesome character for cubes
    let space = " "
    let unicode_rtl = "\u{202B}"

    ExercisesButton.setTitle(unicode_rtl+fa_cubes+space+exercises_heb, for: .normal)
```